# To Set Particular Cell Left Margin of Collection View

Tags: objective-c, xcode

May I know is there any delegate method of collection view can be use to set the left, right margin of particular cell in collection view?

What I've found is as follows,

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{ // my code here }
```

This is to control the left right, top, bottom margin of all the cells within the collection view. May I know is there any delegate function of collection view can be done like

```
UITableView heightForRowAtIndexPath?
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. But since you're going to supply the cells (ie `UIView`) yourself, why not adjust the cell's internal layout yourself?

Comment: Do you mean by adjust the frame of each of the cell?

Comment: I mean adjusting the subviews of the `UIView` that is used as the cell. You can't change the cell's frame as that is controlled by the collection view.